# Can't seem to break a while loop on collision, hashing

Tags: c++, loops, hash, g++

I don't know why this code is not breaking out of the while loop:

```
int table_size = 953;
store hash_table[953];
for(int i = 0; i < table_size; i++)
    hash_table[i].count = 0;

//bunch of stuff to get hash value here

while(hash_table[hashNum].data != pString || hash_table[hashNum].count != 0){
    hashNum++;
    if(hashNum > table_size)
        hashNum = 0;
    cout << hash_table[hashNum].count; 
    // to check the value of the count in the array, it IS 0, thus should have broken the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably mean:

```
while(hash_table[hashNum].data != pString && hash_table[hashNum].count != 0)
```

In your code the loop will continue if either case is true, `hash_table[hashNum].count == 0` is NOT sufficient to make the clause false.

Comment: @kingcong3: Emphasis on the `&&`. At the moment, your code says that "if either of those things are true, keep going". Instead, with the `&&`, it means "If either of those things are false, stop".

Answer (score 1):

`hash_table[hashNum].count` being equal to zero is not sufficient to terminate the loop since you are using `||` ("**or**") between the two conditions in the termination test.  If `hash_table[hashNum].data` is not equal to `pString` then the loop will continue regardless of what `hash_table[hashNum].count` is.

Answer (score 1):

I think your loop condition should be on `hashNum != 0` instead of `hash_table[hashNum].count != 0`.

Secondly, there should be `&&` instead of `||` in your while condition.

These are wild guesses since a lot of information is missing in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at binary logic, especially [De Morgan theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
!(a && b) is equivalent to (!a) || (!b)
```